# á not getting replaced but í does?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to replace `á` with `a` with the following:

```
i.string.replace_with(i.string.replace(u'\xc3', 'a'))
```

But it doesn't replace anything. But if I use

```
i.string.replace_with(i.string.replace(u'\xed', 'i'))
```

It will replace `í` with `i`

Why is the `á` not being replaced but the `í` is? When I am opening/saving files I don't specify which encoding to use. Is this the cause of my problem (of it is how come I can replace í but not á then)?

I am new at python and I am still learning.

Comment: Is it, perhaps, `\xc1` instead of `\xc3` ?

Comment: Instead of trying to replace bytes within a string, you should use the proper encoding in the first place. Wherever you get `i.string` from, read it in accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is in the code you're looking for. In unicode `á` seems to be `\xE1` instead of `\xC3`.

Give it a go and let me know if does work.

You could check some other symbols using converters like this one:
http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some encoding, you can open your file like this;

```
import re, codecs

with codecs.open("filename", 'r', 'utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line 

 f.close()
```

It will return the tokens with the u'flag. It could also be the case that you need to encode with latin-1,encode('latin-1');

```
    import re, codecs

    with codecs.open("filename", encoding="latin-1") as f:
        for line in f:
            print line 

    f.close()
```